# How to run a python script in a shell script on MAC OS

Tags: python, macos, shell

I'm trying to execute a .py file when I run a .sh file in the terminal. But i'm getting this error : /Users/Desktop/folder/script.sh: line 25: ./script_to_execute.py: Permission denied

It seems I don't have the permission... I'm on mac os

Any idea?

thx in advance

Comment: `chmod +x script_to_execute.py && ./script.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F.Leone gave you instructions to fix your problem just add execute rights to your script. Execute in terminal:

```
chmod +x script_to_execute.py && ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm trying to execute it this way : eval $( ./Assemblage/info_planche.py -n "$num" )

Ok, it gives me this : -rwxr--r--@ for the .sh script and -rw-r--r--@ for the .py file.

Thx